# ASP.NET MVC - Crawler - doesn't encode \n

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-crawler, amp-html

Long Description filed has \n in it to give a line break. It works perfectly on default browser mode but doesn't encode for Crawler and AMP page

Tried:

```
  <p itemprop="description" style="white-space: pre-wrap">@Html.Raw(Model.Restaurant.Description.Replace("\n\n", "<br />"))</p>
```

displayed as

**Crawler and AMP mode**

> KFC KFC, until 1991 known as Kentucky Fried Chicken, is an American
>   fast food restaurant chain that specializes in fried chicken.\n\nKFC
>   menu is available online. Order now your KFC food and view their
>   online menu prices

Normal Mode:

> KFC KFC, until 1991 known as Kentucky Fried Chicken, is an American
>   fast food restaurant chain that specializes in fried chicken.
>
> KFC menu is available online. Order now your KFC food and view their online menu prices

Comment: It would be awesome if you provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS [white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```
<span itemprop="description" style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.Restaurant.Description</span>
```

> white-space: pre-line

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the trick!

```
<p itemprop="description" style="white-space: pre-wrap">>@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Restaurant.Description).Replace(@"\n", "<br />"))</p>
```